# Use dynamic variable names in dplyr case_when()

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function in R which uses case_when:

```
myfunction <- function(df, col, case_name, cntl_name) {

object <- df %>%
    mutate(
        class = case_when(
            col == case_name ~ 1,
            col == cntl_name ~ 0,
         )
     )
return(object)
}
```

So if I have this object:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("ID1", "ID2", 
"ID3", "ID4", "ID5"
), phenotype = c("blue", "blue", "red", 
"green", "red"), treatment = c("treat1", "treat2", 
"none", "none", "none"), weeks_of_treatment = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0
)), row.names = c("ID1", "ID2", 
"ID3", "ID4", "ID5"
), class = "data.frame")

> df
     id phenotype treatment weeks_of_treatment
ID1 ID1      blue    treat1                  0
ID2 ID2      blue    treat2                  0
ID3 ID3       red      none                  0
ID4 ID4     green      none                  0
ID5 ID5       red      none                  0
```

And run:

```
newdf <- myfunction(df, "phenotype", "red", "blue")
```

It should return a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   id phenotype treatment weeks_of_treatment class
1 ID1      blue    treat1                  0     0
2 ID2      blue    treat2                  0     0
3 ID3       red      none                  0     1
4 ID4     green      none                  0    NA
5 ID5       red      none                  0     1
```

But it doesn't - it returns this:

```
> newdf
   id phenotype treatment weeks_of_treatment class
1 ID1      blue    treat1                  0    NA
2 ID2      blue    treat2                  0    NA
3 ID3       red      none                  0    NA
4 ID4     green      none                  0    NA
5 ID5       red      none                  0    NA
```

It does not recognise the variable as `col` as the column `phenotype`.  Does anyone know how to input a dynamic variable into `case_when`?

I have tried other solutions for variables in dplyr (eg, using double brackets around col `[[col]]`) but I can't find something that works.

Comment: I think you were closer to a solution with `[[col]]`: `{{col}}` might have worked.  The issue is, I suspect, tidyverse's use of non-standard evaluation, or [NSE](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myfunction <- function(df, col, case_name, cntl_name) {
  object <- df %>%
    mutate(
      class = case_when(
        {{col}} == case_name ~ 1,
        {{col}} == cntl_name ~ 0,
      )
    )
  return(object)
}

myfunction(df, phenotype, "red", "blue")
   id phenotype treatment weeks_of_treatment class
1 ID1      blue    treat1                  0     0
2 ID2      blue    treat2                  0     0
3 ID3       red      none                  0     1
4 ID4     green      none                  0    NA
5 ID5       red      none                  0     1
```

Personally, I prefer

```
myfunction <- function(df, col, case_name, cntl_name) {
  qCol <- enquo(col)
  object <- df %>%
    mutate(
      class = case_when(
        !! qCol == case_name ~ 1,
        !! qCol == cntl_name ~ 0,
      )
    )
  return(object)
}
```

because it makes the separation between environment variables and data frame variables explicit.

The link in my comment is my go-to page when working with NSE.